# MRI scanners in the United States with teslas

Tags: data-request, medical

I am looking for a dataset listing MRI scanners in the United States with as many following fields as possible, ordered by descending importance:

- Location
- Number of teslas (as of now, commercial systems are available [between 0.2T–7T](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Magnetic_resonance_imaging&oldid=717757886#Procedure), and sometimes even up to [10.5 Teslas](https://www.cmrr.umn.edu/magnets/105t88.shtml) (Siemens MAGNETOM 10.5T))
- Whether it is publicly available (i.e., whether a patient can book an appointment)
- Date when it was made available
- Model name

I am mostly interested in the state of Massachusetts.

Comment: spoke with close friend of mine who is a scientist and professor of medical physics for past ten years whose primary research technique is MRI -- he is unaware of any such dataset.

Comment: @BrandonLoudermilk Thanks! Well at least in the answer below we have 60% of the 7T MRI scanners, and 100% percent of the MRI scanners with over seven Testla :-) as usual maybe we should ask Google http://motherboard.vice.com/read/uk-hospitals-are-feeding-16-million-patients-health-records-to-googles-ai

Comment: fyi - had no clue they made 10.5T scanners... wow.

Comment: @BrandonLoudermilk Yes, it's very exciting. e.g. some studies on the usefulness of MRI scanners with seven Testla and above http://health.stackexchange.com/q/5671/43 . My main clinical interest is tendinopathies.

Answer (score 3):

I found this [map](http://www.healthcare.siemens.com/siemens_hwem-hwem_ssxa_websites-context-root/wcm/idc/resources/hwem_assets/mri/htmlApps/terra20150528/index.html?device=mobile&language=en) showing the locations of Siemens MAGNETOM 7T, Siemens MAGNETOM 9.4T, Siemens MAGNETOM 10.5T, and Siemens MAGNETOM 11.7T in the world:

[image]

According to the website, it represents  65% of the 7T MRI scanners, and 100% percent of the MRI scanners with over seven Testla.

[image]

---

Related:  [Number of MRI scanners in the world today?](https://health.stackexchange.com/q/7254/43)

> [Magnetic-resonance.org](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNYiE.png)
>
> > World­wide, there are approximately 36,000 MR machines. At present,
> >     about 2,500 MR imaging units are sold worldwide every year
>
> - This [CDC link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXMKM.png) shows the amount per country.

[image]

From http://www.magnetic-resonance.org/ch/21-01.html :

> Worldwide sales of MR ma­chi­nes by field strength per year between 1982/3 and 2001.  (EMRF|TRTF counts).

[image]

[image]

[image]